# Issue with room calendar in Exchange Online

Tags: exchange, office365

I'm having some issues with room calendars. In our company we have several room mailboxes to allow users to book a meeting room. We've set up automatic handling of the booking requests so the requests are accepted/rejected when the room is available or not. Default users can only see when a room is available or busy, no further details.

However, the people who work at the reception desk should be able to also see the organiser and subject of the meeting, but not the details of the meeting itself. On top of that, they also need the permission to copy the meeting to their personal calendar so that the meetings show up in the calendar pane at the mail view.

I've already granted the reception full access rights to the mailbox of the meeting rooms, but that way they can see the details as well. I've tried removing all permissions and then sharing the calendar with them, with the permission to see the organiser and subject, but then they cannot copy the meetings to their personal calendar.

Is there any way I can set the permissions so that the requested setup is achieved?

We are using Office 365 and Exchange online with AD sync. The users and rooms are created in our on-premise AD. However, if it is easier, I can recreate the rooms in Office 365 (not the users though).

Comment: We had a similar issue in our organization. If you migrate the shared mailboxes to Exhange online and the users are on o365 it will create more problems than solving them. You can either delegate the full access of the mailbox to the reception mailbox or you can give me them view only access to the calendar. There isn't an alternate I know of. Did you raise a ticket with your exchange team?

Comment: Both the room mailboxes and the users are in AD on premise, but synced with O365. Haven't raised a ticket yet, since it doesn't seem a bug to me, rather some incorrect settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot more testing, I finally found the issue. Apparantely the calendars of the rooms where set to delete the subject. This is a setting that can be changed using PowerShell

```
Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails RoomMailbox | Set-CalendarProcessing -AddOrganizerToSubject $false -DeleteSubject $false -DeleteComments $true -RemovePrivateProperty $false
```

Setting the `-DeleteSubject` parameter to `$false` solved the problem of the subject not being visible to the delegates.